# I'm trying to update the year in my MongDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So this is my code

```
router.put('/update/:year', async (req, res) => {
  const year = req.params.year;
    World.findByIdAndUpdate(year, req.body, {new:true})
    .then(data => {
      if (!data) {
        res.status(404).send({
          message: `Cannot update Tutorial with id=${year}. Maybe Tutorial was not found!`
        });
      } else {


        res.send({ message: "Tutorial was updated successfully." })};
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: "Error updating Tutorial with year=" + year
      });
    });
})
```

This code returns a success message when I run it on Postman, but my data isn't updating

[image: Postman screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Can you add a log statement to capture the `req.params`, `req.body` and `data` please?

Comment: Which document are you trying to update? I don't think you're telling the `findByIdAndUpdate()` function, hence it is not matching and changing any documents

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 0):

```
World.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, { year: 2000 }, {new:true})
```